# In iOS 6.1, when use storeKit plugin ,crash

Tags: unity-game-engine

In `iOS 6.1`, when I use `storeKit plugin`, I get a crash when the network is unavailable or something else badly happens.

Here is the stack:

```
 StoreKitManager request : didFailWithError : UnitySendMessage strlen
```

I think in `iOS 6.1`, the `strlen` argument is `nil`. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with prime31 plugin.

You need to update your StoreKit plugin - prime31 repaired it. (prime wrote at 01-30-2013: "- workaround for an iOS 6.1 only issue where Apple will occasionally send null error objects when there is no internet connection")